# Getting an error of isEnrolled null

Tags: node.js, bash, hyperledger-fabric

I am working on invoking chain code by multiple curl commands which is fired from script file, and the chain code is invoked using node server.
When I am trying that I got the following error:

[image: error image]

I tried to invoke chain code 5 times whereas chain code is getting invoked only four times.
Can anyone help me out? Why is it happening like this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please check the version of your `grpc` library in your `package.json`?

Comment: "grpc": ">=1.10.1 <1.11.0",

Comment: Try uninstalling your `grpc` using `npm uninstall grpc` and then install (a downgraded) version 1.9.1 using `npm install grpc@1.9.1` and see if it is working.

Comment: sorry even then its not working